# How to make one normal map on top of another normal map, instead of blending?

Tags: normal-map

How to make one normal map on top of another normal map, instead of blending?

So I'm making a dress, I put two texture of fabric using normal maps.
One for the whole fabric, two, as embroider on certain part of the fabric.
Currently they are look blending with one another. Cos the node used is mix RGB to combine.
But what I need is for the embroider on top of the fabric texture.

Comment: That's an autogenerated comment, but I think that ought to answer your question.  I plan on adding my own new answer to that old question in just a few moments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you're using them as a bump map.  Something like this could work for you.

Run them both through a color ramp (or map range would work too) such that the base fabric is [image: Color Ramp Nodes] the black to grey, and the embroidery is grey to white.

Then use a 'Lighten' node to overlay the embroidery over the fabric.

Tweak the values depending on your exact texture inputs to make them look right.